# Python reading text files

Tags: python

Please help I need python to compare text line(s) to words like this.

```py
with open('textfile', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
    print(f_contents)
    if f_contents=="a":
        print("text")
```

I also would need it to, read a certain line, and compare that line. But when I run this program it does not do anything no error messages, nor does it print text. Also
How do you get python to write in just line 1? When I try to do it for some reason, it combines both words together can someone help thank you!

Comment: pls also fix the formatting for the code :)

Answer (score 0):

what is `f_contents` it's supposed to be just `print(contents)`after reading in each line and storing it to `contents`. Hope that helps :)

An example of reading a file content:

```
with open("criticaldocuments.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
       print(line)
       #prints all the lines in this file
       #allows the user to iterate over the file line by line
```

OR what you want is something like this using readlines():

```
with open("criticaldocuments.txt", "r") as f:
   contents = f.readlines() 
   #readlines() will store each and every line into var contents 
   if contents == None:
      print("No lines were stored, file execution failed most likely")
   elif contents == "Password is Password":
      print("We cracked it")
   else:
      print(contents)
      # this returns all the lines if no matches
```

Note:

```
contents = f.readlines()
```

Can be done like this too:

```
for line in f.readlines(): 
#this eliminates the ambiguity of what 'contents' is doing
#and you could work through the rest of the code the same way except 
#replace the contents with 'line'.
```

Comment: Im kinda confused, I just started learning this stuff could you give me a example of the code?

Comment: sure no problem